# set comprehension not behaving as expected

Tags: python, python-2.7, set-comprehension

Need help on why this code snippet does not return as I'd expect

```
>>> a = 1
>>> v = ["a", "b", "c"]
>>> {e for e in v if locals().get(e) is None}
set(['a', 'c', 'b'])
```

I expected it to return `set(['c', 'b'])`, just like if I build a list

```
>>> [e for e in v if locals().get(e) is None]
['b', 'c']
```

Comment: Closely related: [Python list comprehension rebind names even after scope of comprehension. Is this right?](//stackoverflow.com/q/4198906)

Comment: Near-duplicate: [Python dictionary comprehension gives KeyError](//stackoverflow.com/q/22485399)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Python 2, set and dictionary comprehensions have their own scope; `locals()` inside such a construct refers to that new nested scope.

List comprehensions do not, because they were implemented earlier in the language lifecycle before the developers realised that a new scope would be a much better idea. In Python 3, list comprehensions have their own scope too.

You can work around this by creating a single reference to the dictionary that `locals()` returns *before* running your set comprehension:

```
>>> l = locals()
>>> {e for e in v if l.get(e) is None}
{'c', 'b'}
```